# Why is my PBKDF2 hashing method returning a different output?

Tags: java, hash, salt, pbkdf2

I apologize for my beginner level at cryptography.
While working on my project, I figured the need to hash my passwords before inserting them into DB so I searched for the top hashing algorithms and discovered PBKFD2 and the salt method.

The way I do it is by generating random 64char Salt and use it to hash the password. then Store the hashed password and the salt in my DB. (PS: Passwords are also generated upon registering.NOT MY CHOICE)

Upon login, my Servlet gets the password then hashes it with the salt stored in the DB. Yet I get different results
Here is my code.

```
 public static String generatePassword() {
          CharacterRule alphabets = new CharacterRule(EnglishCharacterData.Alphabetical);
          CharacterRule digits = new CharacterRule(EnglishCharacterData.Digit);
          

          PasswordGenerator passwordGenerator = new PasswordGenerator();
          String password = passwordGenerator.generatePassword(10, alphabets, digits);
          return password ; 
       }
       
       
       public static byte[] hashPassword( final char[] password, final byte[] salt, final int iterations, final int keyLength ) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

            try {
                SecretKeyFactory skf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance( "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512" );
                PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec( password, salt, iterations, keyLength );
                SecretKey key = skf.generateSecret( spec );
                byte[] res = key.getEncoded( );
                return res;
            } catch ( NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException e ) {
                throw new RuntimeException( e );
            }
        }
       
       public static HashMap<Integer,String> hashGeneeratedPassword(String password) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
            HashMap<Integer,String> returnValues = new HashMap<Integer,String>() ; 
            int iterations = 20000;
            int keyLength = 512;
            char[] passwordChars = password.toCharArray();
            byte[] saltBytes = generateSalt() ; 

            byte[] hashedBytes = hashPassword(passwordChars, saltBytes, iterations, keyLength);
            String hashedString = HexUtils.toHexString(hashedBytes); 
            String saltString = HexUtils.toHexString(saltBytes) ;
            
            returnValues.put(1,hashedString); 
            returnValues.put(2, saltString);
            
            return returnValues ; 
        }
       
       private static byte[] generateSalt() {
            SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
            byte[] salt = new byte[32];
            random.nextBytes(salt);
            return salt;
        }
       
       public static String hashLoginPassword(String password,String salt) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
            
            int iterations = 20000;
            int keyLength = 512;
            char[] passwordChars = password.toCharArray();
            byte[] saltBytes = salt.getBytes();

            byte[] hashedBytes = hashPassword(passwordChars, saltBytes, iterations, keyLength);
            String hashedString = HexUtils.toHexString(hashedBytes); 

            return hashedString ; 
        }
```

Thank you for taking the time to read my post.

Comment: When the user first registers (or changes their password) is when you create the salt. Thereafter whenever the user attempts to login you retrieve this salt from the DB and, together with the password,  re-compute the hash, then compare with the stored hash to authenticate the user. You do not generate a brand-new random salt for every login.

Comment: I'm aware of that. That's why i created the hashLoginPassword(password, salt). It hashes the password entered by the user using his own salt retrieved from DB.  Salt is only generated upon registering by hashGeneratedPassword(String password) that returns the generated salt and hashed to be both stored in my DB.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:**
My tool for converting byte[] salt and byte[] hash was wrong. I used HexUtil and everything worked well.